# Access AWS VPC network from GitHub Actions for e2e testing

Tags: amazon-web-services, github-actions, amazon-vpc

We are switching our cicd pipelines to GitHub Actions and I am working to get our e2e tests working in the GHA pipeline.

The scenario:

- We want to e2e test a REST API in GitHub Actions

The need:

- Establish access to our AWS dependencies so that we can run our API in the GHA pipeline and perform e2e tests against our development environment on AWS (databases, IAM, etc...)

The question:

- Should we look for a GitHub Action for each AWS dependency we need or is there a way to establish a secure connection to the VPC network itself?

I have searched StackOverflow (and Google) for questions/answers in this regard but I was unable to find anything directly related. Maybe I am missing something obvious or going in the wrong direction. Any insight would be greatly appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking

Comment: Hi @Paolo, the idea of e2e testing in your CICD pipeline is to run the application with the newly added changes and then execute API tests against said application. It is important that the application has access to any dependencies for it to truly be an end to end test (hence the need for network access to our AWS dependencies).

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66970875/is-it-possible-to-use-static-ip-when-using-github-actions